# Programmatically importing pictures in Excel is getting too slow

Tags: c#, excel, com

I have written a Windows Form application in which for each row of an Excel file, I'm importing a jpg picture located in a server on my intranet network.
The Excel file is made of about 2000 rows.
The code where I insert the picture looks like this:

```
String currentFilePath = getCurrentFileName(pictureDirectory, stagione, currentLine, currentModello, currentMateriale, currentColore);
Excel.Range oRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowIndex, indexColumnFoto];
Picture picture = ((Pictures)xlWorkSheet.Pictures(Type.Missing)).Insert(currentFilePath, Type.Missing);
picture.Left = (double)oRange.Left;
picture.Top = (double)oRange.Top;

if (picture.Height > (double)oRange.Height)
{
    if (picture.Height > 400)
    {
        oRange.RowHeight = 400;
    }
    else
    {
        oRange.RowHeight = picture.Height;
    }
}
```

This operation is running in a BackgroundWorker and everything is working just fine, except that after a while the process is getting very slow.
I have looked for a solution online, but I found nothing. The only solutions I found where related do pieces of code that imported text in an Excel and not pictures.

If you have any idea, please let me know. Consider that my user are complaining, but I think that a software used to import 1500-2000 images in Excel should be quite slow, should'nt it?

One more thing, as you have seen, I used COM to do the work. Is there any other way to import pictures?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

With COM and pulling the data off the server, as you are doing, you are likely only to see marginal improvements with a few tweaks here and there.

First and foremost, for the Excel app, you should set `Application.ScreenUpdating = false;` at the beginning of your routine and then when finished, set it back to `Application.ScreenUpdating = true;`. This will help improve performance a bit.

You may also want to consider grabbing all the pictures first and put them in a `List<T>` object with their height, the target `oRange` and the `oRange.RowHeight` predetermined before putting them in Excel. As you are running this in a BackgroundWorker, this is probably what you'd want to do anyway. Combined with #1 above, you'll likely see some improvements.

If you're using Excel 2007/2010 (this will *not* work with earlier versions), you could use the Open XML SDK instead. It's likely to be far, far faster. This is not a client operation though - the XLSX should be closed when doing this, but the results will only be as slow as bringing the pictures over the wire from your server. Here's a sample of how to insert multiple pictures into Excel with the SDK: http://polymathprogrammer.com/2010/11/10/how-to-insert-multiple-images-in-excel-open-xml/

Answer (score 0):

C# -> Office COM is slow. End of. I've been using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), which is a lot quicker, although it does allow you to create xlsx files that Excel won't open. It claims to do pictures too.